# Python ncurses addstr expected bytes or str, got int

Tags: python, python-curses

I am attempting to create an ASCII level editor in Python using `curses` but I'm having issues. I get `Traceback (most recent call last): File "lvleditor_curses.py", line 36, in <module> editor.newLine() File "lvleditor_curses.py", line 31, in newLine self.stdscr.addstr(self.level[0][0]) TypeError: expect bytes or str, got int` when using the following code.

```
import os, curses

class Editor:

  def __init__(self):
    self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    self.stdscr.keypad(True)

    self.stdscr.addstr("test")
    self.stdscr.refresh()


    self.level = []

  def newLine(self):
    line = self.stdscr.getstr()

    self.level += [list(line)]
    self.stdscr.addstr(self.level[0][0])
    self.stdscr.refresh()


editor = Editor()
editor.newLine()
```

Comment: Please, provide your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 

If you encounter errors, copy and paste the error message into your question.

Comment: What is the type of `self.level[0][0]` at runtime? (with `type(self.level[0][0])`)

Comment: @TwistedSim Updated my post.

Comment: Please, copy and Paste the error message verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue now. The `getstr` function returns a bytearray by default. Therefore you must cast the bytearray to a string. Add:

```
line = line.decode()
```

Under:

```
line = self.stdscr.getstr()
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `self.level[0][0]` is of the wrong type (`int`). Cast it to string with `str(self.level[0][0])`.

Comment: When casting it prints out the ASCII value.